# How can i change my navigation bar tint color

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, navigationbar

How can i change my navigation bar tint color?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cyaL.png)

I already set the bar tint color of navigation bar on attribute.
But nothing happened on the main storyboard and simulator.
What should i do to fix this?
Did i do something wrong when i created navigation controller?

I check some of the boxes on the attribute but it doesn't work.
I googled this problem solving but there is nothing for me.

Comment: Set the title as: "How can i change my navigation bar tint color?" And display the image directly in the question. When questions are clear and well presented, people rush to the rescue. ;)

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer thank you for your advice! i changed the title but i cannot post the image directly. They say i need to earn 10 reputation to post image directly